# Can anyone recommend Chinese names that mean "a rainfall of jade"?

Tags: meaning, mandarin, names

In my opinion, “a rainfall of jade” conjures up a pleasant imagery. The name I’m looking for is intended for a boy. Family name is 白. I was thinking of the name 雨琳 as it’s closer to the English comparative. But would these combination of characters be suitable for a given name for a boy?  People have told me 雨琳 is too feminine for a boy?  Is there any other similar combinations that exude a more masculine tone?

Comment: “a rainfall of jade" is a horrifying scenario.  Imagine how many people would get hurt or die from head trauma.

Comment: Jadeite is a stone.  I wouldn't want to stand under the jade stone rains.

Comment: You're right,「琳」is very feminine. I would suggest 「霖」...

Answer (score 2):

if the family name is 白, may i suggest, for rainfall:

[霝(u+971d)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9C%9D), which means "light rain, drops of rain". it has a heritage since oracle bone script, used for people's name at that period.

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000003720

another one is: [澍(u+6f8d)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%BE%8D), which means "timely rain; to rain, to moisten"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000009123

for jade, roughly all characters belong to the 96 radical "玉" is jade related. i would suggest these four:

[璐(u+7490)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%92%90), [瑾(u+747e)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%91%BE), [琨(u+7428)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%90%A8), or [琦(u+7426)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%90%A6)

so some combinations of a boy's name:

霝璐, 霝瑾, 霝琨, 霝琦, or 澍璐, 澍瑾, 澍琨, 澍琦.

before making any decision, would you consider the baby's [生辰八字](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000132478)? in the past, it's one of the most important factor in choosing any name.

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

琳 used for female's name. You can put 玉 as part of your name and the full name will be 玉霖 .